# Intuition for expectation of log-normal random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

We know that in general we cannot say that for a normally-distributed variable $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$:

$$ E\left[f(Z)\right] \not= f(E[Z]) $$

In particular, given $e^Z \sim \mathcal{LN}(0,1)$ we have:

$$ E\left[e^Z\right]=e^{\frac{1}{2}}>1=e^0=e^{E[Z]} $$

I am trying to get an intuitive explanation for the above case. What surprises me is that $P(Z>0)=P(Z\leq 0)$, so I don't intuitively understand that the expectation of the exponential is higher than the exponential of the expectation.

Comment: Look up Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Thank you @Chappers but I'm looking, if possible, for an intuitive explanation to this particular case.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Laplace Transform?

Comment: Jensen's inequality is intuitive.  A convex function's graph  is above its tangent line at the mean.  For a linear function, $E[f(Z)]$ would equal $f(E[Z])$.  So for a convex function, $E[f(Z)] \ge f(E[Z])$, and $>$ except in trivial cases.

Comment: To be honest I know the expectation if the exponential of a random variable by that name, but it might not be correct terminology.